# How to put space in between ranges?

Tags: excel, vba, range, filenames

Right now i have this code where i tried to insert space between cells:

```
Sub Otdelniy_PDF_GIALLO()

Dim CellValue As String
Dim Path As String
Dim FinalFileName As String
MyString = Space(1)

    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="R:\users402\AUDIT\AUDIT POLAND\AUDIT GIALLO\AUTO_INVOICES\" & Range("A2") & Space(1) & Range("A6") & Space(1) & Range("D4") & Space(1) & Range("B3") & ".pdf"
End Sub
```

I also tried & " " &; + " " +; "&nbsp" - nothing worked out, error 1004

Comment: What's the error message? We don't really study and keep a dictionary of error code..

Comment: Try `"R:\users402\AUDIT\AUDIT POLAND\AUDIT GIALLO\AUTO_INVOICES\" & Range("A2") & " " & Range("A6") & " " & Range("D4") & " " & Range("B3") & ".pdf"`. Make sure the file name is valid. (i.e. no invalid characters)

Comment: I would like to see an explanation on why `...&" "&...` is different than `...&space(1)@...`. True, the first one is shorter but is there another difference ?

Comment: @Luuk I don't think so but why use a function when it's only 1 space? I think the issue is that it's an invalid file name

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

**a)** Use `&`, not `+` to concatenate strings in VBA. `+` will work if you are dealing with strings (and only with strings), but fail if one of terms is a number because in that case VBA will try to add numbers. `&` is explicitly for string concatenation.

**b)** There is not difference between `" "` and `space(1)`, so it's just a matter of taste.
`&nbsp` will not work, it is unknown to VBA - and even if it wasn't, it wouldn't work as a non breakable space character is something different than a space character.

**c)** You should write the filename into a variable and dump it to the immediate window. Have a look at the output, most likely you either have a typo in the name or you are referring to cells of the wrong sheet - currently your code accesses the active sheet which is maybe not what you expected.

**d)** If the filename looks okay to you, copy the name into the clipboard, switch to Excel and try the export manually, using the filename from the immediate window.

```
Dim pdfFilename As String
pdfFilename = "R:\users402\AUDIT\AUDIT POLAND\AUDIT GIALLO\AUTO_INVOICES\" _
            & Range("A2") & Space(1) & Range("A6") & Space(1) & Range("D4") & Space(1) & Range("B3") _
            & ".pdf"
Debug.Print pdfFilename 
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfFilename
```

Comment: While I can see how this answer is helpful to OP... just a friendly reminder that if you think this issue is caused by a typo... there's a flag for that. Ultimately, if this question won't be useful to anyone in future, neither will this answer.

Comment: @CallumDA This is the general problem with SO nowadays: There are hardly any questions that will be useful to anyone, at least not for VBA. At least OP tried something before asking.